# Use Modal (Bootstrap) on Symfony

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, bootstrap-modal

I have a survey that I created (eat.html.twig) and on my profile.html.twig page I have my link for this survey. What I want to do is instead of being sent on this page I want to display the survey in a pop-up. I can do it on the same file twig with no worries, but when it comes to another file I cannot do it.

I read that it was necessary to use AJAX, but the way to do it is not very clear to me.

Here my twig {{profile.html.twig}}

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body">
            {{ render(controller('AppBundle\\Controller\\SiteController::managerAction'))}}//---- {site_manager.html.twig}---//

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I specify that the questionnaire is already OK. I just want to display it as a pop-up on my profile page

Comment: Hi, try this `{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Site:manger')) }}`. Also, is there is no misspelling in the action name (manger<>manager)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor all instances of *manger* so that they are replaced by *manager*. This won't change anything, except that it will make your code easier to read. Delete the CSS link on *manager*.html.twig and put it on base.html.twig. For more information on base.html.twig see the *Template Inheritance and Layouts* section in the [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html).